# git diff shows more files than were edited

Tags: php, git, gitlab

Situation.

1. I pulled project from master.
2. I change some file and commit it to gitlab.
3. CI job runner must check codeSniffer eventual errors for edited files only.
4. CI Runner launches a command to find edited files:

   ```
   git diff --name-status master...commit
   ```
5. git returns modified files...

The problem is what I see bigger modified files list, than I modified.

I tried to set:

```
git config core.autocrlf true
git config core.filemode false
```

No success
Is any solution for it?

Comment: `-c` doesn't set anything in config, it allows running one command as if given entry were set. To set config, use `git config core.autocrlf true`

Comment: Thank you for correction, but I tried many different ways, also yours, unfortunately no influence and result the same :(

Comment: what does "eventual" mean in this context?

Comment: possible code style errors

Comment: We need more information, preferably a [mcve]. The `git diff master...<commit-hash>` syntax will locate a merge base commit and diff that merge base commit against the specified commit hash ID based on the local repository's `master` name, which may or may not be what you want to achieve here. Actual examples are likely to help pinpoint things though.